# Finding derivative of inverse of a function.

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Let $f(x) = x^3 + e^x + ln(x + 1) + 3x^{\frac{4}{3}}$. If $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ then find the value of $g'(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ so we can write $x = f(g(x))$. Differentiating this equation we get $$g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$$
Now we have to find $g(1)$ i.e. the solution of $f(x) = 1$ which can be found intuitively as $x = 0$. Thus $g(1) = 0$. As $f'(x) = 3x^2 + e^x + \frac{1}{x+1} + 4x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ so $f'(0) = 2$.
Therefore $$g'(1) = \frac{1}{f'(g(1))} = \frac{1}{2}$$